# Can I earn secret hats by playing Hat Dash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, secret-hat, hatdash

I know this is supposed to be a secret, but...

I've finally made it to the Hat Dash leaderboard, but was disappointed to find that I got no secret hat from it.

My question is, can you get secret hats from getting high scores in Hat Dash?

Comment: I've only managed to get secret hats apart from the social distancing ones.  And I wasn't paying attention to what I did to get them.

Comment: The whole point of a secret hat is *it's a secret*! (You can get Meta rep by [finding bugs in it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358104), though!)

Comment: @CodyGray Hmm, at least *part* of the point of a "secret hat" must be that it's a hat ;)

Comment: Evidently not, @cigien, considering [many of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917) are not, in fact, hats. Some are trucks, ladders, swords, instruments, and flags on a pole.

Comment: @CodyGray Huh, indeed many of them are not even hats. Well, that's a misnomer if I ever saw one.

Comment: Maybe I am blind but "Hat Dash" whats that and where to find it?

Comment: @RandRandom go to https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com and press the hat dash button and then you can play the game :)  You need to jump over the hats in the game.

Comment: @RandRandom You must wear the Social Distancing hat on any site before you get access to it

Comment: Here is a list of all hats, including secret, with some of the secrets already revealed... [Winter Bash 2020 hat list  ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list)

Comment: @ cornonthecob / RayWu - though I was still struggeling to find it, this button was no where to be found, even though I double/triple checked if I am wearing a social distancing hat, but I finally found it, what I was missing was that I simply wasn't logged in when I accessed the page https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/ I had to click on "Login / Register" at top right, though I didn't actually needed to login manually, after clicking it the page picked up my credentials

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure about the hat from the **Hat Dash** but as per your current collection of hats in your wardrobe, all of them are available from the open market like *Stack Overflow*, *Meta Stack Overflow*, *Stack Exchange Network*.

It doesn't looks like there will be any secret hat either.

Even the *top scorers* from the *Overall Stats* of [Hat Dash Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard) doesn't have any unique (secret) hat.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible to get secret hats from Hat Dash, because it has no parent site.

What I mean by parent site is that it can't give the secret hat to a specific site, because the Hat Dash has no parent site.

It's pretty unfortunate...

Comment: Could just default to Meta StackExchange, I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: "I don't think (X is possible). What I mean by (X) is that (X isn't possible)." Did you mean to rephrase the second paragraph? It says the same thing as the first one.